# PhD Thesis Publications

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

As part of planning ahead for a PhD in Theoretical Physics, I wanted to read some of the published PhD thesis, so as to get an idea of choice of topics and the depth of research. Unfortunately, although I could find the list of Thesis Topics done by previous PhD students in institutes like Harvard or Berkeley, I could rarely find any pdf copies nor DOI for a vast number of thesis papers.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest me sources where I could find PhD thesis pdf versions in Theoretical / Mathematical Physics in general.  Also, is there any reason why PhD Thesis are not made public, or is it that they didn't care to digitalize it? In particular I am referring to [Harvard](https://www.physics.harvard.edu/academics/phds1971-2000) or [Berkeley](https://physics.berkeley.edu/academics/graduate-degrees/past-dissertations).

Comment: In some cases you can access Theses by the university library. But that might require a university account, and I don't know how Harvard or Berkeley handle this.

Comment: You can look through Harvard physics theses here - https://dash.harvard.edu/browse?type=department&value=Physics. PDF versions are available if the author agreed to make them public.

Comment: arxiv is a site that accepts physics papers, it does not do peer review, but there is a general check of mainstream physics . I searched with google "arxiv thesis physics theory" and thesis manuscripts  come up. If there are particular thesis you  want to look for search if they are published on arxiv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most PhD theses are internal university publications, rather than journal publications (though in many cases the material contained in the dissertation is also submitted as one or more journal publications). So to find the thesis itself, you'll have to figure out how to navigate that university's library. When I finished my PhD a dozen years ago, I had the option of preparing a physical, printed and bound copy of my dissertation to live on the shelf on the library's sixth floor, or of submitting an entirely digital document, or both.  That might have been the first year that a paper copy was *not* required by my university's library.  I chose all-digital; I kind of regret not making a few archival-quality paper copies.

Learning to use a research library is a non-trivial part of getting a PhD. A comment under your question links to the [Digital Access to Scholarship at Harvard](https://dash.harvard.edu) database, but the comment link goes to a list of all open-access documents deposited from the Physics department, most of which are not theses. If you choose "Communities & Collections" > "Faculty of Arts & Sciences" > "FAS Theses and Dissertations" then you can browse just theses and dissertations, but you can't limit them by department, and they only seem to display in groups of three. There is probably a better interface than this that I haven’t found in ten minutes of looking.

For the [Berkeley library](https://www.lib.berkeley.edu/), search their [local catalog](http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/) for “berkeley dissertations physics” ([source](https://guides.lib.berkeley.edu/dissertations_theses)).

You can also use databases like [ProQuest](https://www.proquest.com/) or [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/) which catalogue dissertations in their own special category; you may need to find a library with a subscription to get full use of those databases.

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much. Both ProQuest and WorldCat seems to contain a lot of open access ones.  Also just to clarify, my impression was dissertation is usually the paper published at during Masters while Thesis refer to a PhD paper. A quick Google search seems to give little clue. Are these to terms used interchangeably in Science Academics? Also if you don't mind I would like to keep the question open for a couple more days, just in case someone decides to add more.

Comment: The terms are mostly interchangeable. In US English a "dissertation" is a more substantial piece of scholarship, and some undergraduates will prepare a "senior thesis." [Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis) in UK English the weights are reversed.